# Вызов виртуальных методов в конструкторе наследника

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

```
struct A {
    A() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

struct B : A {
    B() : A() {
        foo();
    }

    void foo() override {
        // B's implementation
    }
}

struct C : A {
    C() : A() {
        foo();
    }

    void foo() override {
        // C's implementation
    } 
}
```

Это легальный код? Если да, то слышал, что вызов виртуальных функций в конструкторах является плохим стилем. Как можно переписать это без таких вызовов? Достаточно ли обернуть вызов `foo` в обычную функцию?

upd:

Дополнил вопрос, чтобы показать, зачем нужна виртуальность -- для единого интерфейса в разных наследниках `A`

Comment: Ваш пример по-прежнему непоказателен. Можно убрать `A::foo` и всю виртуальность - и ничего не поменяется.

Comment: пока вы из конструктора класса А не начнете вызывать foo() всё легаьно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие вызовы виртуальных функций из конструктора совершенно легальны, но при этом надо учитывать, что во время работы конструктора класса `T` динамический тип конструируемого объекта - это именно `T`, даже если в реальности конструируемый объект типа `T` является базой какого-то более крупного объекта. То есть "виртуальность" вызовов в иерархии классов будет ограничена снизу классом `T`. Функции из классов, расположенных ниже `T` в иерархии, через такую виртуальность вызываться не будут.

Оборачивание вызова `foo` в обычную функцию никак на это поведение не повлияет.

В вашем примере вызов `foo` из конструктора класса `B` будет всегда попадать в `B::foo`, а вызов `C::foo` из конструктора класса `С` - в `C::foo`. Фактически никакой виртуальности в вашем примере не получается (не нужно) вообще, т.е. все довольно тривиально. Пример не показателен, т.е. не ясно, чего вы хотели получить на основе виртуальности `foo` и, соответственно, как и зачем это переписывать по-другому.

Comment: Сейчас дополню, чтобы пояснить зачем виртуальность

Comment: и нужно учитывать, что в функции может генерироваться исключение

Comment: Ну а если в будущем, кто-то захочет унаследоваться от `B` или `C`, там задать свою реализацию `foo`? Тогда он будет ожидать вызова своего `foo`, а будет вызван только `foo` базового класса в базовом классе

Comment: @ferma: Да, именно так. Даже если кто-то унаследуется от `B` и определит свою `foo`, вызов `foo` конструктора класса `B` будет все равно всегда будет попадать в `B::foo`.

Comment: @AnT так вот, поэтому такой стиль считается плохим. Как можно это переписать, чтобы вообще не вызывать виртуальных функций **в конструкторах**, но всё же иметь одинаковый интерфейс (не просто сделать foo1, foo2)?

Comment: Тут нет никакого "стиля", а есть просто стандартное поведение. Он не считается "плохим". "Плохим" его называют только те, кто возлагал на него неоправданные ожидания, а они не оправдались. "Переписать" ваш код легко: выкиньте вообще `A::foo`. Виртуальность пропадет, а больше ничего не поменяется. Поэтому я не пойму, о каком именно "переписывании" вы ведете речь. Приведите более конкретный пример.

Comment: @AnT Так интерфейс не будет единым. Я не смогу, скажем, из указателя на `A` вызывать виртуально нужную мне функцию

Comment: @ferma: Но из вашего примера совершенно не видно, почему `foo` вообще должна являться частью единого интерфейса.

Comment: @AnT согласен. Эта `foo` вызывается виртуально из других мест программы в общем

Answer (score 0):

Просто оберните вызов виртуальной `foo()` в невиртуальную `bar()`